# error "import static com.sun.corba (...)"

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm coding on Netbeans, what does this error mean and could I solve it without resetting?

```js
error: package com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi does not exist
import static com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;
D:\Unknown\Documents\Netbeans_Projects\Roar_1\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:14: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;
Note: D:\Unknown\Documents\Netbeans_Projects\Roar_1\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
D:\Unknown\Documents\Netbeans_Projects\Roar_1\build.xml:50: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I attach the screen below

[image: error message on my screen]

Possibly it is because I selected > Add import for `com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request` for the box Request, once some red symbols of bug appeared on my code:

[image]

Comment: You simply need to remove the problematic import statement from your class. It looks something like this: `import com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;`

Comment: Thanks, I did it but now I get this error (screen) :

https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/imageAssetProxy.v1/5yyjTqgVEeWKww7cgKAxYw_9aba90696d55e260cc901665174c70d8_1.png?expiry=1450828800000&hmac=uAi4_gYAXyeibkiyhYblEkIi3sWpgcgzZvUWtKPu-vw

Comment: You didn't remove it. You moved it to the bottom of the file. Delete that line.

Comment: Ok (sorry I could not find it firstly), I removed it and now I can launch the preview, thank you.

Comment: I've posted an official answer to your question. Feel free to accept it as the correct answer, if you'd like.

Comment: ok, I did it , thank you.

Comment: You may have upvoted the answer (thank you), but accepting it is different. Click the check mark below the Answer score to accept it.

Comment: ok, sorry, I'm new to this forum. Now I did it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that you have an errant import statement in your class file. Look for a line that looks like the following:

```
import com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;
```

or

```
import static com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;
```

Simply remove that line to get rid of the error.